# How to write the values of a certain variable on the graph in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the stress levels of people with different education between 2018 and 2021.

I use the following code and it works fine:

```
ggplot(x, aes(year, stress)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = education, linetype= education)) +
  labs(group= "Education", linetype="Education")
```

However, it is not clear for the reader at what stress level the initial values started. For example, it shows for the low educated stress levels started somewhere between 5 and 6 in 2018, but i would like the reader to see the values of 2018 graphically for both educational groups. This means that it should write "5.6" for the low educated and "4.3" for the high education on the graph. What would be the best way to do it?

Here is the reproducible example:

```
structure(list(stress = structure(c(4.30000019073486, 4.5, 6, 
7.40000009536743, 5.59999990463257, 6.19999980926514, 8.80000019073486, 
8.80000019073486), format.stata = "%9.0g"), year = structure(c(2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    education = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("High", 
    "Low"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create a label column and show the value for `stress` in 2018 using `geom_text`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

x %>%
  mutate(label = replace(round(stress, 2), year != 2018, '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, stress, label = label)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = education, linetype= education)) +
  labs(group= "Education", linetype="Education")  +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]